# Linear algebra orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, orthonormal

Assume that A ∈ M<sup>n×n</sup>(R) admits an orthonormal basis of
eigenvectors with eigenvalues λ<sub>1</sub> ≤ λ<sub>2</sub> ≤ · · · ≤ λ<sub>n</sub>.

Show that λ<sub>1</sub>∥v∥<sup>2</sup> ≤ Av · v ≤ λ<sub>n</sub>∥v∥<sup>2</sup> for each v ∈ R<sup>n</sup>

So far I've got:

⟨v<sub>i</sub>,v<sub>j</sub>⟩ = 0 for i= ̸=j for an orthonormal basis

but I'm not sure about where to go from there

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: $Av\cdot v=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_{k}|<v,v_k>|^2.$ Next, how can you express the norm $v$ using the given orthonormal base?

Comment: How do you decompose $v$ in that base?

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help! I think I've managed to do the question now by multiplying out the inner products for Av.v and λ1∥v∥^2 respectively and using the fact that λ1 ≤ λ2 ≤ · · · ≤ λn to get the inequality.